# Pass a function with arguments as argument

Tags: c, function-pointers

I want to pass a function with arguments as argument into some other function, but I don't know how (or if) I can do that.

What I want to do is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void getInput(char* request, int (*func)());

int main()
{
    double input;
    getInput("Input: ", scanf("%lf", &input));
}

void getInput(char* request, int (*func)())
{
    // do stuff
    func()
    // do more stuff
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. I think the scanf is getting executed when I'm trying to pass it as an argument.
How do I get this to run in getInput?

Comment: Note that while C may not support it, libraries like [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/) can do this, and cross-platform too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that in C, the language doesn't support such a construct.

You can often solve this exact type of problem using variable-arguments functions again:

```
void getInput(const char *request, const char *fmt, ...)
{
  va_list args;
  printf("%s: ", request);
  fflush(stdout);
  va_start(fmt, args);
  vscanf(fmt, args);
  va_end(args);
}
```

Usage is like this:

```
int main(void)
{
  double input;
  getInput("Input", "%lf", &input);
  return 0;
}
```

Of course you might want to add proper return-value handling, otherwise it's impossible to know if the embedded `vscanf()` succeeded so the variable is OK to use.

Comment: Can we replace the `fflush` call by appending a `'\n'` to the format string of `printf`?

Comment: @ajay Sure, but that would put the prompt on a line by itself which is not quite as nice-looking. Flushing `stdout` is fine, that's basically the core usage case right there. :)